# How to build a self-contained net core web app targeting ClousLinux?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to publish a self contained dotnet app to a web host running CloudLinux. When I ran the app, the Segment fault (core dump) error. The app was built using the RID centos-x64. The app runs on centos 8 and Fedora 29 (x64). But when I try to build this app with the RID centos, I get the 'NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'centos'.'

`dotnet publish -c Release --runtime centos --self-contained true`

This is the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>centos</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Any suggestions to what is wrong?

Comment: Try `linux-x64` which is more generic.

Comment: Linux-x64 caused the Segment fault error. That is the reason for wanting to try centos.

Comment: Then it is a very interesting question you should bring to the CloudLinux vendor as it is their responsibilities to work with Microsoft, not you. Microsoft alone can only support a small set of distributions (https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-supported-os.md).